# Setting lower limit to interpolation using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, interpolation

I have rainfall data that I want to interpolate using spline. I have done Spline Interpolation, only that the values produce negative predicted values which is basically wrong. There should be no negative rainfall value.

How can I set lower limit to zero or set a true value limit?

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the question is whether you want a "sawed-off" floor, which you would get with approaches like the one recommended by @radouxju. This is usually fine and is really pretty easy to do.

If you want to get a little fancier and have the algorithm respect that floor and fit it into the overall interpolation a little more smoothly, then try to use an interpolation algorithm that lets you limit the minimum values (and maximum ones, too!). One example is [`TopoToRaster`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Topo_to_Raster/009z0000006s000000/).

Comment: It seems that TopoToRaster has solve my issues at least on preliminary level. I'll try to explore this and get back to you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To set negative values to zero, you can use the map algebra tool ( Con(myraster < 0, 0 , myraster).

However, it is better to use another interpolation method. In you case probably IDW (inverse distance weight) will be good enough